# Order by latest date of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Image` that contains columns `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt`.
My goal is to write a SELECT that would be ordered by the latest of these 2 dates.

`UpdatedAt` can be NULL, then I have to ignore it.
I need both ascending and descending sorting depending on parameter.

I was trying the following:

```
  ...order by Image.updatedAt, Image.createdAt
  ...order by Image.updatedAt desc, Image.createdAt desc
```

Unfortunately the results were not correct. I suspect incorrect comparisons with NULLs that were in `UpdatedAt`

I have also tried to apply `max` to both columns, but such approach appears to be working only with nested select.

Could anybody advise a good solution, please?

Comment: `order by coalesce(Image.updatedAt, Image.createdAt)`?

Comment: `UpdatedAt` will always be a date later than `CreatedAt` correct?  If so then use the `COALESCE` solution.  If not (which wouldn't make sense to me, but hey I've seen stranger things) please indicate so another solution can be worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to order by the first non-null values of the two, and it just so happens `coalesce` returns the first non-null value of its parameters:

```
order by coalesce(Image.UpdatedAt, Image.CreatedAt)
```

In SQL Server, you can also use `Isnull()` which is optimal if you only have two values.

Comment: It works, Thanks, any idea about the performance of the clause when UpdatedAt has null values